# join lines for email

Tags: email, python-2.7

I'm using the following to read a file content in order to email it using gmail smtp on a windows machine

```
f = open(filename, 'rU')
lines = f.read().splitlines()
content = "\r\n".join(lines)
```

The problem is that the email I get has the lines all joined with no newline.
I have tried the join with "\n", "\r" "\r\n\r\n", and even r"\r\n" but regardless of what I try I get the lines joined.

This question was asked a million times and has billions of answers, but I cannot find a working one.
BTW, printing "content", in the cmd window, works fine.

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: Well, I found out that doing content = "<br>".join(lines) works. HTML to the rescue. But the question is still valid.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you even need to splitlines and then join them again? You can read the whole content with:

```
 f = open(filename, 'rU')
 content = f.read()
```

Comment: Did you read the question? Its not about how to read the file, its about how to get the newlines after it gets emailed. Just reading it result is no newlines whatsoever in the email.